# Can a Jenkins agent be on the same node as the Master?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am just starting with `Jenkins`, and I am confused on the `Remote root directory`, the `WorkDir` and the `Internal data directory`, precisely on their full path, including `Hostname`.

The agent is supposed to be on a different node, but I don't see where we can specify a `Hostname` or `IP address`.

The examples `Remote root directory` I have seen so far looks like `/var/jenkins`, is it on the master node ? if not how or where do we specify the remote `Hostname` or `IP address` ?

Same for the `Workir`, is it remote or local ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your jenkins master node can run builds and works as an slave too.

Remote root directory is on the slave.
Manage the slaves is in section "Manage Nodes".
Specify the hostname/IP Address in the launch method option: "via SSH"

To join a slave:
https://medium.com/@chathurams.sa/step-by-step-guide-to-add-jenkins-slave-nodes-f2e756c8849e

Comment: Ok, I see that it depends on the Launch method. The default one (Launch agent by connecting it to the master) is a bit confusing.

Comment: yes, no problem. If you run a windows slave, it is the other way round. You connect from the Slave to the master via the URL and download the jenkins installer. :)

Comment: @s8k-37 beat me to the answer., though pls add this: You can actually setup multiple agents (slaves) on same host. Make sure to SSH using a separate user to the one Jenkins master is installed as otherwise there's a security vulnerability risk. Make sure the "Remote root directory" is unique; that's where the workspaces are created inside of  (An agent needs to have a directory dedicated to Jenkins).. Recommend setting "Remoting Work directory" inside  "Remote root directory" *where it stores the agent.jar, etc). ps::you can also run multiple masters on same host w/care, diff. user etc.